# Generating function for partitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, infinite-product

It is a theorem of Euler that $$\sum p(k)x^k=\prod\frac{1}{1-x^k}.$$
Something which annoys me is how to interpret the right hand side. I know that one can do this analytically, but I would like a purely algebraic interpretation, where the left hand side is viewed as formal power series. Is it possible to give such an interpretation?

Comment: When you say algebraic, would a calculation of the partition numbers by convolving infinitely many matrices that correspond to the right hand side be an answer to your question? Gary W. Adamson taught me this with his aerate convolve algorithm.

Comment: The Mathematica program that corresponds to the right hand side: https://mobiusfunction.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/partition-numbers-with-gary-w-adamsons-aerate-convolve-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: in several books, e.g. Bourbaki, one finds that the infinite product of formal power series is sometimes defined, and it turns out that it is defined in this case, $1/(1-x^k)=1+x^k+x^{2k}+...$

Answer (score 0):

Write this as
$\sum p(n)x^n
=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^k}
=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{jk}
$.

Whenever the sum 
of the terms $jk$
is $n$,
that contributes to $p(n)$.
So,
whenever
$n
=a_1+2a_2+3a_3+4a_4+...
$,
where the term
$a_i$
comes from the sum for
$\frac1{1-x^i}$,
that
will contribute to
$p(n)$.
If you consider *all* possible sums
of that form
that total $n$,
you get the total
number of partitions.

Look at Hardy and Wright,
or Andrew's book on partitions,
or
Generatingfunctionology,
or ...,
and you will see this formula explained
more clearly than I have done here.